# Accord.net Cobyla solver returns success when there are no feasiable solutions

Tags: f#, nonlinear-optimization, accord.net

I'm using Accord.Net's Cobyla solver to solve a rather simple non-linear problem. In some cases there will be no feasible points for the problem.
When I run even a simple problem where the non-feasibility is obvious, the solver return "Success" even though the solution is not feasible.

Consider the following example, written in F#:

```
open System.Collection.Generics

let obj12 = QuadraticObjectiveFunction("a - a*a");
let c12 = QuadraticConstraint(obj12, Array2D.zeroCreate 1 1, [| 10.0 |],    ConstraintType.LesserThanOrEqualTo, 4.0)
let c13 = QuadraticConstraint(obj12, Array2D.zeroCreate 1 1, [| 10.0 |], ConstraintType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, 45.0)

let p1 = List<NonlinearConstraint>()
p1.Add(c12)
p1.Add(c13)
let solver1 = Cobyla(obj12, p1)  
let success = solver1.Maximize()
let value = solver1.Value
let solution = solver1.Solution
let r = solver1.Status
```

The solution the solver is found is 4.5 which clearly violate the first and second constraints however the solver status is "successful".

Is that a bug/feature? Any workaround?

Comment: As Anders noted, this behavior comes from the original Fortran 77 implementation. However, I will be adding a new status code for this specific situation in the future. Thanks for raising this question!

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the C# COBYLA code that is the basis for the *Accord.NET* version of COBYLA. The C# implementation is a fairly straightforward translation from FORTRAN 77 of Michael Powell's original code.

The optimization method currently only supports three return statuses:

- Normal termination
- Maximum number of function evaluations reached
- Rounding errors are increasing in an uncontrolled way

There exists no explicit indication saying that constraints are violated. COBYLA strives to meet the constraints, but is not guaranteed to succeed with this and may return without having fulfilled the constraints.

If I interpret your example correctly (my F# knowledge is a little rusty for the moment) you have two contradicting constraints, or? As a possible workaround, I would otherwise suggest that you select a variable start guess that at least approximately fulfills the constraints; that should make it easier for COBYLA to stay within the feasible region.