# Setting constraints in Accord.net (this should be easy?)

Tags: vb.net, accord.net

I have a [Cobyla](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Math_Optimization_Cobyla.htm) object in a VB project (which could just as easily be C#) for solving a problem with 7 variables. Each variable has its own constraint. I'm setting up the constraints like this, but the constraints aren't being followed.

```
Dim mesaConstraints As NonlinearConstraint() =
    {' Make sure all variables follow their constraints
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(0) >= min0),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(1) >= min1),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(2) >= min2),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(3) >= min3),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(4) >= min4),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(5) >= min5),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(6) >= min6),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(0) <= max0),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(1) <= max1),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(2) <= max2),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(3) <= max3),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(4) <= max4),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(5) <= max5),
    New NonlinearConstraint(7, Function(mesaVar) mesaVar(6) <= max6)
}
```

Is anyone able to suggest why the constraints aren't being followed? I would think it would be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check that the cobyla exit code (the status property [2]) is CobylaStatus.Success to ensure that the solution is valid.
According to Anders Gustafsson there is no guarantee that constraints are met [1].

[1] [Accord.net Cobyla solver returns success when there are no feasiable solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567946/accord-net-cobyla-solver-returns-success-when-there-are-no-feasiable-solutions/30569263#30569263)

[2] http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Math_Optimization_Cobyla.htm